# Negative numbers with modulo operator in 'De-Vigenere' program

Tags: c, encryption, vigenere

I am making a program that decrypts the vigenere cipher. User can only give alphabetical key.

```
for (int i = 0, counter = strlen(text); i < counter; i++)
    {
        // prints non-alphabetical characters straight away
        if (!isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", text[i]);
        }

        else
        {
            // for index of key
            index = meta % strlen(key);

            if (islower(text[i]))
            {
                // separate cases depending upon case of key
                if (islower(key[index]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((text[i] - 97) - (key[index] - 97)) % 26) + 97);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%c", (((text[i] - 97) - (key[index] - 65)) % 26) + 97);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (islower(key[index]))
                {
                    printf("%d", (((text[i] - 65) - (key[index] - 97)) % 26) + 65); 
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%c", (((text[i] - 65) - (key[index] - 65)) % 26) + 65);
                }
            }
            // incrementing for next key alphabet
            meta++;
        }
```

### Vigenere:

- Input: MyName
- key: qwerty
- output: CuRrfc

### De Vigenere:

- Input: CuRrfc
- key:qwerty
- expected output: MyName
- given output: 3_NaSK

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you know you have a problem with [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) you probably know where the problem is, and the solution to all operator precedence problems is to use parentheses.

Comment: Also, please try to avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by e.g. `65` you mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) encoding for `'A'` then *use* `'A'`.

Comment: Furthermore, I assume that `meta` is properly initialized in both your programs?

Comment: Yeah. Meta tag is initialized. I was wrong in the first place. The problem was not with the operator precedence. It was with the modulo operator and the negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way the modulus operator deals with negative numbers.

For some characters you get negative values and the modulus operation then returns a negative value. You want a value in the range [0, 25].

You can fix it by adding 26 before taking the modulus.

```
                printf("%c", (((text[i] - 97) - (key[index] - 97)) % 26) + 97);
```

would become

```
                printf("%c", (((text[i] - 97) - (key[index] - 97) + 26) % 26) + 97);
```

Change all four rows the same way.

Comment: It also depends which operand is negative. For example `-10 % 3` is `-1`, but `10 % -3` is `1`. The rule to remember is that integer division truncates towards 0 (discarding the fractional part), and that `((a / b) * b) + (a % b)` equals `a`.